# Poetry: Managing PyPI dependencies without version number

Tags: python, package-managers, python-poetry

I'm trying to use Poetry to manage my python projects, but some PyPI dependencies don't have a version number such as [this one](https://pypi.org/project/waapi-client/).

I thus get such errors

```sh
$ poetry update
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.5s)

  SolverProblemError

  Because wworkflow depends on waapi-client-python (^0) which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.

  at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/puzzle/solver.py:241 in _solve
      237│             packages = result.packages
      238│         except OverrideNeeded as e:
      239│             return self.solve_in_compatibility_mode(e.overrides, use_latest=use_latest)
      240│         except SolveFailure as e:
    → 241│             raise SolverProblemError(e)
      242│ 
      243│         results = dict(
      244│             depth_first_search(
      245│                 PackageNode(self._package, packages), aggregate_package_nodes
```

I got the similar error when using `any` as the version value of the dependency in .toml.

Is it that Poetry does not support such a usecase?

Comment: @python_user I tried it and the version is not recognized by poetry

Comment: Shouldn't it be `waapi-client` not `waapi-client-python`? Did you add the dependency via `poetry add`?

Comment: @lain SHelvington. Oh, i took the name from its GitHub repo as opposed to PyPI pacakge name. But Poetry doesn't even know the name is wrong? Anyways, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Lain Shelvington's comments. I got the package name wrong. I took the name from its GitHub repo, but the PyPI package is named differently.

`poetry update` works after fixing the name. However, Poetry's inability to distinguish the package name error from its version tag issue is a bit confusing.